# Problems operating a server through the Internet with a Public IP. Socket and Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking

I am learning to use socket in python3. I am developing a small chat that works as follows.

- The server receives the request from a client to connect.
- The server accepts it, and adds it to its "listen" list.
- When the client sends a message, the server receives it.
- The server sends the message to all users that are not the sender.
- Repeat for all clients.

If you run it on my local machine by specifying "localhost" in the
server.bind () there is no problem.

The problem arises when, through a No-IP or my own IP publishes I try to make it work.

Clients connect to the server, and I can send a first message, which all clients receive. but when I send more messages from any client, nothing happens, but the connection is still alive between the clients and the server. I do not have an error message.

Actions that I made before this consultation.

- Open ports on my router, firewall, and OS (Windows10 x64).
- Use a DUC NO-IP  so that ISP can change my public IP and not be a problem.
- Try for other Internet Conection with open ports.

I really think it's a server problem.

Full code of my program.

**Client**

```py
import socket
import threading

class ClaseCliente():

    def __init__(self):

        # Configuramos el tipo de conexion y nos conectamos al servidor.
        self.cliente = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.cliente.connect(('publicIP', 1337))

        self.nick = input("Selecciona tu nombre de usuario: ")

        # Ponemos un thread a recibir los mensajes.
        mensajeRecibido = threading.Thread(target=self.RecibirMensajes)
        mensajeRecibido.daemon = True
        mensajeRecibido.start()

        # Bucle que mantiene vivo el bucle y ademas nos permite enviar mensajes.
        while True:
            mensaje = input()
            try:
                if mensaje != "salir":
                    self.EnviarMensajes(mensaje)
                else:
                    self.cliente.close()
            except:
                self.cliente.close()


    def RecibirMensajes(self):

        while True: # Bucle que mantiene viva la recepcion de mensajes.
            try:
                mensaje = self.cliente.recv(2048)
                print(mensaje.decode()) # Por defecto el encode es "utf-8".
            except:
                pass


    def EnviarMensajes(self, mensaje):

        mensaje = self.nick + "- " + mensaje # Agregamos el nick al mensaje. 
        self.cliente.send(bytes(mensaje.encode())) # Enviamos el mensaje codificado al servidor. Por defecto, en "utf-8".

# --------------------------------------------------------------#


start = ClaseCliente()
```

**Server**

```py
import socket
import threading

class ClaseServidor(): 

    def __init__(self):

        # Configuramos el tipo de conexion y nos ponemos a escuchar 
        self.servidor = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.servidor.bind(('0.0.0.0', 1337))
        self.servidor.listen()
        self.servidor.setblocking(False) # No bloqueamos la conexion (Genera una excepcion si no puede mandar o recibir datos).

        # Ponemos un thread a aceptar las conexiones.
        aceptarConex = threading.Thread(target=self.AceptarConexiones)
        aceptarConex.daemon = True
        aceptarConex.start()

        # Ponemos un thread a leer y reenviar los mensajes entrantes.
        manejoMensajes = threading.Thread(target=self.ManejarMensajesEntrantes)
        manejoMensajes.daemon = True
        manejoMensajes.start()


        # Bucle que mantiene vivo el servidor.
        try:
            while True: 
                Mensaje = input(" =>  ")
                if Mensaje == "salir":
                    self.servidor.close()
                    break
        except:
            self.servidor.close()


    def MandarMensajes(self, mensaje, emisor):

        for receptor in self.listaConexiones:   
            try: 
                # Si la persona que envia el mensaje no es el que lo recibe, envia el mensaje.
                if emisor != receptor:
                    receptor.send(mensaje)
            except:
                # Entramos en la excepcion si no se puede enviar el mensaje a alguien, y lo quitamos de la lista de clientes.
                self.listaConexiones.remove(cliente)


    def AceptarConexiones(self):

        self.listaConexiones = [] # Lista para guardar las conexiones

        while True: # Bucle que mantiene escuchando 
            try:
                clienteConexion, clienteIP = self.servidor.accept() # Empezamos a aceptar conexiones 
                clienteConexion.setblocking(False)
                self.listaConexiones.append(clienteConexion) # Agregamos el objeto cliente a nuestra lista.
                print("se ha conectado el cliente: ", clienteIP[0])
            except:
                pass # Esto es para el setblocking, si se puede aceptar, da una excepcion.


    def ManejarMensajesEntrantes(self):

        while True: # Bucle que mantiene vivo el manejo de mensajes.
            if len(self.listaConexiones) != 0: 
                for cliente in self.listaConexiones: 
                    try:
                        mensaje = cliente.recv(2048) # Recibimos un mensaje.
                        self.MandarMensajes(mensaje, cliente) # Lo mandamos a enviar.
                    except:
                        pass # Esto es para el setblocking, si no recibe un mensaje, da una excepcion.

# --------------------------------------------------------------#

start = ClaseServidor()
```

Comment: Have you tried it from another computer behind the same firewall (and therefore within the NAT, if there is one)?  This would be the best way to tell if the problem is the server program/computer or a networking issue.  Do you have a packet monitoring program like WireShark or `tcpdump` available on the server? That's a good way to watch the actual network traffic when debugging networking programs.

Comment: @gaige Right now I was using wireshark to see the route of the packages. These arrive at the server, but never leave there.

I have tested in the connection of my girlfriend, of which I opened the ports myself, and with the connection of my mobile phone, opening the ports with the application "fwd port forwarding". Thanks for comment :)

Comment: Have you confirmed that `MandarMensajes` is getting called in your `ManejarMensajesEntrates` method?

Comment: I call "MandarMensajes" in this line? `self.MandarMensajes(mensaje, cliente) # Lo mandamos a enviar.
`Thanks for answer :)

Comment: I know that's what is in the source code, but do you know it's actually being called? Perhaps put a print in before the call to make sure the call is actually made. As you indicate, this works on localhost, but there's some difference when the data comes across the network.You need some additional information to know how far into your Servidor process it's getting.

Comment: I have edited the code and put a print in front of each step that the message takes for my program.

@gaige The first message of the first client that sends a message arrives at "ManejarMensajesEntrantes" and "EnviarMensajes". The rest of the messages do not reach anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct and the network configuration too. The problem came from my ISP, which did not assign me a Public IP, instead They was assigned a private IP. That network that had a Public IP. They was offered for a high price, to have a real Public IP, so the solution was to hire a VPS and mount the server there with exactly the same configuration as I indicated in the question.

The solution to the problem: Ask your ISP if there is a problem with having a private server in your home, if it exists, hire a VPS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not entirely certain what the blocking issue is on your system.

A spin loop, like the one you are using to service input is highly inefficient.  You're already using separate threads, so there's really no reason to prevent blocking entirely. On the *server* process, you're going to want to use `select` to monitor for data availability on the server.

Keep in mind that `select` (which works on sockets on Windows according to the docs, at least) will need to be interrupted and restarted in order to add or remove a connection to the list of "watched" items.  You can do that with a local socket between the threads -- so, you basically send a TCP message to the `ManejarMensajesEntrantes` thread from the `AceptarConexiones` thread which will complete the select and cause you to go around the while loop one more time so that you can restart the select with the new (or removed) connections. In a unix-only environment, I'd use a PIPE between the two threads, as it's more straightforward and requires less setup, but select is documented as only working on sockets under Windows.

When used correctly `select` is highly efficient and can also be used to watch for errors on the existing connections (such as the network connection closing), so you can use that to watch for errors on those sockets which you should then remove from `listaConexiones` before calling select again. To monitor errors and incoming data, you'll need to put `listaConexiones` and your communications socket in both the *rlist* and *xlist* for the `select`. Of course, you should call `select` with a zero `timeout` so that you do not spin on the `select` call.

I did some tests on my computer (Mac, and thus unix-based) running your exact code above and although the server process used a lot of CPU cycles because of #1 above, the simple chat function worked fine. The same tests done with a second Mac on the same network also worked ok and I could send and receive multiple messages from multiple clients.

Comment: That helped improve my code, but it didn't solve the problem. thanks for your help